# Filter table values on JSP with values from SQL database

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to make an servlet-based application that gets values from a SQL database and presents them in a dynamically created table on a JSP, which is already working. The next step is to create some sort of filter that only exhibits the table lines that have a certain value in one of its columns. My idea was to add a dropdown menu and select the lines with that item in the "Problem" column. I believe that to be a bit straightforward. The catch is that the values to fill in that dropdowm menu are in a table "Problem" on the SQL database; and each of its rows have the id and name attributes. Currently, I'm trying to go with the `name` attribute and trying to compare it with the "Problem" column that is obtained from my query (SQL Server 2008 R2) (

```
SELECT h.[name], c.[department], p.[name] AS problem, it.[name] AS interaction, ip.[title], ip.[date]
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Input] ip, [Database].[dbo].[Interaction] it, [Database].[dbo].[Problem] p, [Database].[dbo].[HelpdeskUser] h, [Database].[dbo].[Costumer] c
WHERE h.[id] = ip.[user_id]
AND it.[id] = ip.[interaction_id]
AND c.[id] = ip.[costumer_id]
AND p.[id] = ip.[problem_id]
ORDER BY date DESC";
```

), but, obviously, I'm hitting my head against the wall because this isn't working. So I'd like to ask you if you can help me somehow with this and if I'm overlooking something obvious that could unlock this whole process.

#### ViewInputServlet.java

```
public class ViewInputServlet extends GenericServlet {

    public static final String PROBLEMS = "problems";
    public static List<Problem> problems;

    private void setProblems(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws EmptyResultSetException {
        Session session = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        if (ProblemDAO.hasRecords(session)) {
            problems = ProblemDAO.selectProblems(session);
            req.setAttribute(PROBLEMS, problems);
        }
    }
}
```

#### ViewInput.jsp

```
<% List<Problem> problems = (List<Problem>) request.getAttribute(ViewInputServlet.PROBLEMS); %>
<div class="innerField">
    <table class="datatable" id="tableResults">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                <th>PROBLEM</th> 
                <th>TITLE</th>
                <th>DATE</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <%  for (Issue issue : (List<Issue>) request.getAttribute(ViewInputServlet.LIST)) {%>
        <tr>
            <td><%=issue.getName()%></td>
            <td><%=issue.getDepartment()%></td>
            <td id="prob_type"><%=issue.getProblem()%></td>
            <td><%=issue.getTitle()%></td>
            <td><%=issue.getDate()%></td>                
         </tr> 
         <%}%>        
    </table>
        <div class="label">Show by Problems:      </div>  
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui-widget">
                    <select name="<%=ViewInputServlet.PROBLEMS%>" id="chooseProblems">
                        <%if (problems != null) {
                            for (Problem problem : problems) {%>
                            <option value="<%=problem.getName()%>"><%=problem.getName()%></option>
                            <%}
                    }%>
                </select> <input type="button" value="Reset" id="btn_reset" />
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
```

(the column "Problem" is the key here: it's the one I want to filter values by, and that's why I've given it an ID, in a previous attempt that failed)

#### Functions.js

```
$("#chooseProblems").change(function () {
    $("#tableResults").find("td").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text !== $("#chooseProblems").val())
            $(this).hide();
        else
            $(this).show();
    });
});
```

If there's some more info you require or doubts on my reasoning, ask away :)

Comment: when you select a value in the dropdown menu are you querying the database or just filtering the elements in the html view?

Comment: @JavierMollá, my main idea was to filter the results from the full table (and reset it when pressing the "Reset" button, but that may be done a lot later).

Comment: And shouldn't you be passing problem_id value to your query to add to the end: `AND ip.[problem_id] = :problem_id`, only in the case you're filtering

Comment: @JavierMollá The thing is, I was thinking this filtering to be done with Ajax on the HTML view... but maybe sending the problem_id is the best plan, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Could there be a problem with your string comparison in java script. should you be using match method instead of !==.

Also when you say $(this).text or $(this).hide or $(this).show , you are actually referring to column of row not the row.

Comment: Yeah... my plan was faulty. I hate JS.